# Is there a way to setup a minecraft server that me and my friend can play on together?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting

My problem is that I want me and my friend to be able to play on a survival world together, but we live at different locations. I know I can visit a hosting website but I don't want to pay money because it's just me and my friend. Would there be any way for us to play together without paying any money? My problem is different from that one because we don't want to connect through LAN he is at a different location than me.

Comment: @imulsion It's not an exact duplicate, since the linked question is asking about LAN and this question is asking about a remote connection. The answer is the same either way, though.

Comment: @MageXy The linked question discusses port forwarding too. The rule of thumb is if the linked question successfully answers this question, then it's a duplicate.

Comment: @imulsion It's a good rule of thumb, but I would like to emphasize that it's not set in stone. Just because an answer in a different question happens to answer this one does not immediately imply this is a dupe. You could argue that the answer in the linked question goes above and beyond what that OP was originally asking for, and in doing so happened to answered this question. The linked question itself, though, is asking specifically about a local connection, whereas this question requires details for a remote connection.

Comment: That being said, I agree with you (and have voted) that this question should closed as a dupe, since it is more or less the same question with different starting parameters.

Comment: Both of you, @MageXy and Imulsion, unless the OP states that his question is not a dupe, VTCing is just fine.

Comment: The thing is, I cannot use port forwarding because I do not have access to the router

Comment: @Surprisejedi you should add that to your question to differentiate it from the other questions. As of right now, your question is not different.

Answer (score -1):

### How to host a Minecraft Server

The only way to be able to play with your friend if you live in different location is to setup your own minecraft server. Before I continue, I'd like to warn you that creating a server does take a bit of computer and networking skills. I would put up a whole guide to doing it, but as I had a lot of problem with it myself, I'll just refer you to the Minecraft Wiki Page that will help.

Minecraft Wiki: [How to setup a server](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server)

If you're still having trouble, just do some quick searches on Google or Youtube (I'd recommend Youtube as there are more results) to find any problems you have with setting up a server.

Comment: Linking elsewhere for the steps does not constitute an answer here.  Please summarize the relevant steps from the linked page to ensure your answer is still valid, in the event the site ever goes down.